# How to store multiple Dataframes in the Map[String, Dataframe] and access each dataframe by using key of the map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have multiple dataframes which are needed to store them in the Map[String, Dataframe] data structure. Next the goal is to access them for join operations. These are the input dataframes:

```
 names_df:
 +-----+----------+----------+
 |Id   |FirstName | LastName |
 +-----+----------+----------+
 |1000 | Bob      | B        |
 |1001 | Alice    | A        |
 +-----+----------+----------+

 addresses_df
 +----+----+----+
 |Id  |Address  |
 +----+---------+
 |1000|NY       |
 |1001|Boston   |
 +----+---------+
```

I have created a Map as bellow:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,Dataset}

var  map_DFs =Map.empty[String,DataFrame] 
map_DFs += ("Names" -> names_df)
map_DFs += ("Addresses" -> addresses_df)
```

I am trying to load and then join these dataframes with the following code:

```
var person_df =  map_DFs("Names")
person_df =  person_df.join(map_DFs("Addresses"), "Id", "left")
```

However, the results is following error:

```
notebook: error: overloaded method value join with alternatives:
  (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumns: Seq[String],joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, String, String)
     person_df =  person_df.join(map_DFs, "Id", "left")
```

I wonder if you help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The column name should be wrapped into scala Seq if have a join type.

Answer (score 2):

The join key has to be a Column type or a Seq of String:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
person_df =  person_df.join(map_DFs("Addresses"), col("Id"), "left")
//OR
import spark.implicits._
person_df =  person_df.join(map_DFs("Addresses"), $"Id", "left")
//OR
person_df =  person_df.join(map_DFs("Addresses"), Seq("Id"), "left")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method call is not valid, if you want to specify the join type, then you must provide a sequence of join-columns:

```
person_df =  person_df.join(map_DFs("Addresses"), Seq("Id"), "left")
```